# Cant retrieve remote json data

Tags: php, json

I have my json data [here](http://geryit.com/_gazel/reviews_json.php?pid=0) : 
I cant call data from my own website to my local site.
When I copy the same file to local root, it works.
I changed the chmod of the remote file and added some headers but no change. Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, I see the problem was I didnt use jsoncallback=?
so this is the

**js code**

```
$.getJSON('http://geryit.com/_gazel/reviews_json.php?jsoncallback=?',{pid:1},function(data){
    if(data.length){
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            console.log(data[i].title);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the

**php code**

```
include "db.php";
$pid = $_GET["pid"];
$q= mysql_query("select * from reviews where pid = $pid");
$reviews = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) $reviews[] = $r;
$reviews = json_encode($reviews);
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"]."(".$reviews.")";
```

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because cross site scripting in JavaScript is forbidden. For remote calls you can use JSONP or create a proxy which simply grabs content using curl.

Comment: this is  not tagged as javascript

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so I guess JavaScript is involved in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

assumed, you get a response (otherwise it should be an problem of your setting of allow_url_fopen):

What you get there is not regular JSON, your JSON is surrounded by Parentheses.

Furthermore you should provide the JSON utf8-encoded, otherwise you'll get problems, if there are non-ASCII-chars inside.